# Birt UnsupportedFormatException

Tags: java, birt

I using birt version 3.7.0.

I'm trying to create a PDF file. Every time I get an error.

code:

```
private byte[] generateAttachment(Map<String, Object> reportParams) throws EngineException {

IReportRunnable design = this.reportEngine.openReportDesign(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
                                                     ATTACHMENT_PATH).getFile());

// Create a task to run and render the report
IRunAndRenderTask runAndRenderTask = this.reportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);

// Set parent class loader for engine
runAndRenderTask.getAppContext().put(
                     EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY,
                     CAFInjectorService.class.getClassLoader());

// Set report parameter values and validate
if (reportParams != null)
    runAndRenderTask.setParameterValues(reportParams);
runAndRenderTask.validateParameters();

// Setup PDF renderer
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption();
pdfOptions.setOutputFormat("pdf");
pdfOptions.setOutputStream(outStream);
pdfOptions.setOption(
             IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW,
             IPDFRenderOption.FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE);
runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);

// Run and render the report
runAndRenderTask.run();
runAndRenderTask.close();

return outStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.UnsupportedFormatException: The output format pdf is not supported.
```

EDIT: I only have this birt related gradle dependenccy:

```
compile group: 'org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt', name:'org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt.report.engine', version:'3.7.0'
```

Do I need another?

EDIT 2:

added :`compile group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', name:'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', version:'4.4.1'`

and got this error trying to download the depenencies:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'XXX'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
   > Could not resolve r(*);runtime-&gt;runtime:    <dependency:rg.eclipse.birt.runt.
     Required by:
         :XXX:unspecified > org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.4.1
      > Illegal character in path at index 55: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/r(*);runtime-&gt;runtime/    <dependency/rg.eclipse.birt.runt/    <dependency-rg.eclipse.birt.runt.pom
      > Illegal character in path at index 55: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/r(*);runtime-&gt;runtime/    <dependency/rg.eclipse.birt.runt/    <dependency-rg.eclipse.birt.runt.pom
   > Could not resolve org.milyn:flute:1.3.
     Required by:
         :xxx:unspecified > org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.4.1
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: CachedResource: C:\Users\lior\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.milyn\flute\1.3\b0f8da138f675101a0f6d54e6d0882d922bf1557\flute-1.3.pom for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/milyn/flute/1.3/flute-1.3.pom Errors: bad group: expected='org.milyn' found='milyn'
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: CachedResource: C:\Users\lior\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.milyn\flute\1.3\b0f8da138f675101a0f6d54e6d0882d922bf1557\flute-1.3.pom for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/milyn/flute/1.3/flute-1.3.pom Errors: bad group: expected='org.milyn' found='milyn'
```

Comment: Can you please let us know where in the code you are receiving the error message?

Comment: runAndRenderTask.run();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `org.ow2.orchestra` did to BIRT; I'm using [mt4e](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Tools_4_Eclipse) to convert the official Eclipse BIRT bundles to JARs which Maven can process. Unfortunately, this is a rather lengthy/complex process :-(

You need to check whether they have a dependency to `org.apache.batik.pdf` somewhere; in my code, the bundle `org.eclipse.birt.runtime` pulls that in.

Comment: The error message suggests that you're trying to mix BIRT versions. org.ow3 uses BIRT 3.7 and you tried to add BIRT 4.4 to that. That won't work. Also, there seems to be a typo somwhere (`r(*);runtime-&gt;runtime`). And `flute-1.3.pom` has a bad dependency. First, try with BIRT runtime 3.7.0.